# Android boot completed notification not received after reboot

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver registered in the application manifest to receive the BOOT_COMPLETED notification. After restarting the mobile device I receive no notification. However, I do receive the notification when I open my application. Please assist.

Receive boot completed permission from my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Receiver from my manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BootCompletedReceiver class:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Boot Completed Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some suggestions online that except the `BOOT_COMPLETED` action you also need the `QUICKBOOT_POWERON` that is supported by some devices.
You can check this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17221679/944070) for details.

Trying to implement this I also had to add the `android:enabled="false"` and then on demand when the user select it I programmatically changed this to `android:enabled="true"` but this a bit more complicated to try.

You can start by changing your code with this to see if it works.

```
<receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver" 
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In case you like to try the disable logic and then enable this programmatically to do it use this code:

```
private static void changeBootStateReceiver(Context context, boolean enable) {
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootCompletedReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            enable ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
                    : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

I also like to disable the feature when I no longer need it.

**Special cases:**

Depending on device manufacturer there are some reports for different broadcasts upon boot:

- [Xiaomi MIUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30259729/944070) use: `android.intent.action.REBOOT`
- [HTC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17221917/944070) use: `com.htc.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON`

Comment: I have tried your solution but I am still not receiving this. I tried in OnePlus mobile

Answer (score 2):

Check in your device that the app is allowed to run in background (sorry, am not yet able to comment).

You might also want to try **LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED** on Nougat and above. See the [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot.html?hl=en) here. It allows you to listen to actions before the user unlocks the screen.

Comment: @madlymad, where does the second piece of code go?